# Distributed program with libssh

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssh, libssh

I am designing a distributed program using C/C++ based socket communication. Basically, I have one server program `S` and three client programs `A`, `B`, and `C`, and client programs communicate with the server program `S` through customized socket port. Instead of manually starting the four programs (`S`, `A`, `B`, and `C`), I want to use libssh to create ssh session(s) and send `exec` method to run client programs. However, I am a bit confused by the definition between `ssh session` and `ssh channel`. In my case, I would like to run ssh API on server program `S` to invoke these three client programs on remote hosts. Should I use one ssh session with three channels or three ssh sessions with one channel each?

Comment: Unless all three run on the same host, you have to use three sessions. A session is a connection. A channel is a logical stream (or set of streams) of data sent over that session.

Comment: OK I see! Thank you!